# How would you handle different themes in a Vue app?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2, vue-component

I am thinking dynamic styles based on what theme is selected is the best bet but was wondering if anyone had any other ideas for this. I'm using Vuex to store the state for the theme name.

Is there any way to have a component use different stylesheets based on a global state?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have `themeA` and `themeB` and you store those values with Vuex. So, I'd put those main classes in the main component to, lets say, to `#app` (`App.vue`), like:

```
<div id="app" v-bind:class="{ 'theme-a': isThemeA, 'theme-b': isThemeB} "></div>
```

Where with Vuexs getter you get a boolean value for those states.

Later, in `SomeComponent.vue` I'd use `theme-*` selector to style them:

```
<template>
  <div id="some-component">
    <!-- your markup -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'some-component'
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  .theme-a {
    .some-selector { //styles for theme A }
  }

  .theme-b {
    .some-selector { //styles for theme B }
  }
</style>
```

Which would work just fine.